# How to compute binomial random variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I the book we have following problem:
Let X be a Binomial random variable with n = 10 and p = 0.4. Compute the following:

(a) $E[(3 + 5X)]$;

(b) $E[(2 + X)^2]$;

(c) $Var(4 + 3X)$;

I am not sure how to approach this problem having some expression for random variable.
I know that Binomial Random Var. expectation is computed using following formula:
$$E[x] = np$$
and $$Var(x) = np(1-p)$$

Though, I am not sure what does it mean to compute
$E[(3 + 5X)]$ and book does not clarify it. It simply gives all those formulas...

Need your help! Thanks

Comment: **Hint:** $E[\cdot ]$ is a linear operator.

Comment: @IvoTerek does it mean that I can rewrite :
E[(3+5X)] = E[3] + 5E[x]?
And E[3] = 3
then E[x] = 4
So E[(3 + 5x)] = 3 + 5 * 4 = 23 ?

Comment: That's right.${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Var(Y) = E[Y^{2}] - (E[Y])^{2}$.

So to calculate $Var(4 + 3X)$, consider first $E[16 + 24X + 9X^{2}]$. You can break this up using the linearity of the expected value. Similarly, consider $E[4 + 3X]$ and square the result.

Comment: Or, more simply, remember that $\operatorname{var}(a+bX)=b^2\operatorname{var}(X)$ is a very useful identity to memorize.